# Probability convergence and almost surely convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\Omega, \Im ,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $\left\lbrace X_{n} \right\rbrace {}_{n}$ be a sequence of random variables such that
$$\mathbb{P} \left(X1>X2>...>0\right)=1$$
Proof that if $X_{n}$ converges in probability to zero, then $X_{n}$ converges almost surely to zero

Comment: what have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: I need some hint to start the proof or something. I'm lost in this problem.

Comment: The hint is: If $X_n$ converges to $0$ in probability, then there exists a subsequence $(n_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ such that $X_{n_k} \to 0$ almost surely as $k \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of how you can proceed:

1. The assumption  says that  $\{X_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is monotone decreasing almost surely (the set where this does not hold has measure zero). Thus, $X_n\searrow X$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ almost surely for some random variable $X$ (The values of $X$ outside the set where monotonicity holds are not relevant).
2. If it is know that $X_n$ converges to $0$ in probability, then by a well know [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propA1i), $X_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely among a subsequence $\{X_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
3. Combining (1) and (2), one concludes that $X=0$ almost surely. Thus, $X_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely.